# How can an Android application have zero activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have studied in a book that "In Android, an application can have zero or more activities. Typically applications have one or more activities...".

So what are the situations where an application can have "zero" activities? Is there any example of such an application?

Comment: It's not good practice to create an app without some form of user interface. The main point of an `Activity` is to provide a UI - even if your 'app' is only meant to provide some sort of 'service' it is better to have at least a basic 'setup' `Activity` which allows the user to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using some `service`. Just take an `example` of `SoftKeyBoard` service demo provided by Android.

If you want to see, just open Eclipse
File > New > Other > Android_Sample_Project > select version(2.2 o other) > SoftKeyboard >...

Answer (score 3):

For example if you only define a `Service` in an application, you don't need any `Activity`.

Comment: How would you start that `Service`?

Comment: Service don't need to be running unless an application demands it service by calling `startService()` or `bindService()`.

Comment: Typically it might be a persistent service which might be started during booting.

Comment: You can make a persistent service if you want to as well. IMHO it's stupid to have a process running doing nothing, specially on limited hardware like phones, where battery consumption is a key feature. Once needed by any application, Android will start the service. For once, this is well designed.

Answer (score 2):

An Activity is just **one** of the *Building Blocks* of an Android Application.

For Example,Your **'Contacts' App** is actually *two* apps - one with the **Database(Content provider)** and another with the **UI (Activities)**

You **may check if the above is true** by going into `Settings->Applications>Installed` on your android phone/emulator

Check out the first few videos here to get a clear picture : http://marakana.com/s/android_bootcamp_series_2012_video_tutorial,1017/index.html

Comment: fixed the link above. Check again if it didn work the first time